# How to pass a variable in a command in UNIX?

Tags: shell, variable

I am a completely new user to UNIX shell programming. I want to know how I can pass a variable that is now a comment to another comment which is for getting a file from a website. For example:

I have made this variable as a command:

```
password1=$(.....)
```

and my new command is like this:

```
wget "http://.........?something&thecommandiscontinues"
```

I want to replace the word something with the output from my password1 command, so that I do not have to write a new script and manually enter it myself.
Please help me with writing simply and giving me solution. I have been working on this problem several weeks, but not resolved yet. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not something like `http://...?password=something&...` where `something` is meant to be URI-encoded?

Comment: Try `(set -x; curl -GO --data-urlencode "=$password1" -d thecommandiscontinues  http://........`)

Comment: No, `set -x` is so you can have a visual feedback of what command is being run. You need to replace `.....` with the host name and path of the file (something like `host.example.com/path/to/file` without the trailing `?`) `thecommandiscontinues` is the text after the `&` you have in your question! Add a `-v` option to `curl` to see what HTTP request is being made. And if that doesn't work, please tell in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: `$password1` contains spaces characters. If you had done `printf '"%s"\n' "$password1"`, you would have seen them. You probably need to change the command that retrieves the password.

Comment: Add another `s/^ *//;s/ *$//` to your sed command to remove leading an trailing space characters. Now what if the password contains space characters? It's common to have spaces in passwords.

Comment: If you want to remove all the `"`, `:`, `,` and space characters, just use `tr -d '":, '`. No need for `sed`

Comment: tr -d does not work. tr doesn't become blue when I type it. If I want to remove another word can I add it among the characters?

Answer (score 3):

Replace `something` with `${password1}`

Answer (score 1):

So if i did get it right you want to add what is in the variable password1 to the input of the command wget?

If this is the case try creating a fuction like this:

```
myFunction () {
    wget -arg "something[...]$password1"
}
```

You can call this function in your code using this:

```
myVariable=$(myFunction);
```

You will get the output of your command in that variable.

Comment: Should I write anything in the brackets after myFunction?

Comment: I edited my post so i specify how to call the function:You can call this function in your code using this:                

myVariable=$(myFunction);                  
You will get the output of your command in that variable.